# Error rendering R Code in R Presentation between custom divs

Tags: r

I am having an issue being able to render R code when I put it in a custom div in R Presentation. So I setup a new class of divs which separates data into two columns, but R code in those divs returns back the markdown text.

````
<div class="two-col">
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)    

# Read data
annotation_data = read.csv("Data/chr7_15_qtl_genes.csv")

annotation_summary = read.table("Data/chr7_15_qtl_genes_summary.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

#Move factors of evidence around for graphing
annotation_data$Evidence = factor(annotation_data$Evidence, levels(annotation_data$Evidence)[c(1,2,5,3,4)])

#Counts of predicted functions from Provean
ggplot(annotation_data, aes(Evidence, group=1)) + geom_bar(stat="count", aes(fill=Evidence)) + labs(y="Count", title="Count of predicted Functions") 
grid.table((annotation_summary[1:20,1:2]))
```
</div>
````

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this before and have any ideas on how to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a work around but I hid the output and just directly created img tags for the created graphs. Hopefully, this will be helpful to some people.

````
<div class="two-col">
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)    

# Read data
annotation_data = read.csv("Data/chr7_15_qtl_genes.csv")

#Move factors of evidence around for graphing
annotation_data$Evidence = factor(annotation_data$Evidence, levels(annotation_data$Evidence)[c(1,2,5,3,4)])

#Counts of predicted functions from Provean
ggplot(annotation_data, aes(Evidence, group=1)) + geom_bar(stat="count", aes(fill=Evidence)) + labs(y="Count", title="Count of predicted Functions") 
```
  <img src="eqtl_presentation-figure/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png">
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
#Show table of annotation summary
annotation_summary = read.table("Data/chr7_15_qtl_genes_summary.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
grid.table((annotation_summary[1:20,1:2]))
```
  <img src="eqtl_presentation-figure/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png">
</div>
````